# Multiple Regex Data Annotation Validation

Tags: c#, regex, data-annotations

I have a string field in my Code First which can contain one of the two regular expressions:

```
([0-5]\d):([0-5]\d)\,(\d{2})
or
(\d{3}),(\d{2})
```

How can I combine them in one field? I tried using a custom validation. The field validation is always true, even if I enter just letters. I can't find out what I'm doing wrong.

```
[CustomResult]
public string Resultstring { get; set; }
```

and

```
public class CustomResultAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        // 00:00,00
        if (Regex.IsMatch(value.ToString(), @"([0-5]\d):([0-5]\d)\,(\d{2})")) 
        {
            return true;
        }

        // 000,00
        if (Regex.IsMatch(value.ToString(), @"(\d{3}),(\d{2})")) 
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think in this case, you can just use an or `|` in your regex:

```
([0-5]\d):([0-5]\d)\,(\d{2})|(\d{3}),(\d{2})
```

Put this into http://www.regexper.com/ to see.

Comment: Wow, can't believe I looked over this. Thank you very much! It worked.

Answer (score 3):

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

[RegularExpression("^([0-5]\d:[0-5]\d,\d{2})|(\d{3},\d{2})$"]
```

Comment: @Aschratt  I disagree.  In the OP's given example code, he is already using data annotations; this post is clarifying how to use the standard data annotation given for validating against regular expressions.